# Keydown Play Audio with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keydown

I'm making a drum machine for FreeCodeCamp but I'm struggling to make the audio play when specific keys are clicked.
My latest attempt can be seen in handleKeyDown.
The function is receiving the event, and I'm able to render which key is being hit, but not sure how to make the src play.
I'm not sure how to make the if statement work, or the code inside the if statement.
I've removed some code which I deemed irrelevant to the problem.
How should I approach this? Many thanks.

```
    const sounds = [
  {
    key: 'Q',
    keyCode: 81,
    id: 'Heater-1',
    url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3'
  },
  {
    key: 'W',
    keyCode: 87,
    id: 'Heater-2',
    url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3'
  }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.audio = React.createRef()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeydown);
  }

  componenetWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeydown);
  }
  
  handleKeydown = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === this.props.keyCode) {
      
      const audio = document.getElementById(this.props.key);
      audio.currentTime = 0;
      audio.play();
    }
  }
  


  render() {
  return (
    <div id="drum-machine">
      <div id="drumpad">
      {sounds.map(i => (
            <button
              className="drum-pad"
              id={i.key}
              key={i.key}
              onClick={this.handleClick}
              value={i.key}
            >{i.key}
            <audio 
            className="clip" 
            id={i.key}
            src={i.url}
            ref={this.audio}
            /></button>
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//file for export, comm.js
export const AudioPlay = (file) => {
  new Audio(`/static/sounds/${file}`).play();    //under folder public
};

//file import
import {AudioPlay} from './comm';

//in your event function
AudioPlay('stockin-ok.mp3');
```